# Parallax scroll background image auto zoomin and zoomout

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, parallax

Want to out o zooming zoom out images I am trying it from CSS  and normal jQuery  function  effect onscroll  but not working.

Scroll  I am adding CSS for zooming but it's not zooming out.

http://ucanedu.in/uraban/#home

Any help is greatly appriciated.

Comment: Add your code here...

Answer (score 2):

For a parallax scroll effect, your best bet is to use a simple CSS animation with 3 or 4 layers, animating the background from 0 to 100% as shown in this [example](http://codepen.io/StevenIseki/pen/uilcC) or this [one](http://codepen.io/stefanjudis/pen/nrzHI)

```
@keyframes animatedBackground {
  from { background-position: 0 0; }
  to { background-position: 100% 0; }
}

animation: animatedBackground 80s linear infinite;
```

For a CSS animation zoom in and out, this is not really a parallax effect, it is just zooming in and out, for this you could use a css transition on the container element as shown in [this example](http://codepen.io/StevenIseki/pen/CDpwy)

```
transition:All 1s ease;
transform: scale(3) translateX(120px);
```

Comment: i want zoom-in and zoom out but this example image going on horizontal scrolling  . so please can you tell me how my background image can be zoom in and zoom out

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by zoom in and out. Did [this](http://codepen.io/stefanjudis/pen/nrzHI) example help you, it is a vertical scroll

Comment: for that nice 3d spin effect use rotate3d [example here](http://www.w3.org/Talks/2012/0416-CSS-WWW2012/Demos/transforms/demo-rotate3d.html), if you are looking for something a bit easier, [jQuery Transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) is pretty nice at doing CSS Animations as well